# Multiple odata servlets and endpoints - is it possible?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, web-applications, odata

I am using oData servlets for my web application and would like to add additional endpoints for it.

For example: /odata/* 
And also: /pathVariable/{pathVariable}/odata/*

while "pathVariable" serv me for passing additional data and variables.

I tried duplicating the servlet method and direct it to a new URL mapping unsuccessfully.

This is my current code:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean odataServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean<CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet> odataServlet = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet(), "/odata/*");
    Map<String, String> initParameters = new HashMap<>();
    initParameters.put("javax.ws.rs.Application", "org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.rest.app.ODataApplication");
    initParameters.put("org.apache.olingo.odata2.service.factory", "com.context.JPAServiceFactory");
    odataServlet.setInitParameters(initParameters);
    return odataServlet;
}
```

My expected result is multiple endpoints available for oData use:

/odata

/pathName/data/odata/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to create 2 different servlets as 2 different and distinct OData services?

If so, you can try defining your OData servlets and their endpoints by using javax's @WebServlet annotation and letting Spring scan for them.

For example, 1st service:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/odata/*"}, initParams = {
        @WebInitParam(name = "javax.ws.rs.Application", value = "org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.rest.app.ODataApplication"),
        @WebInitParam(name = "org.apache.olingo.odata2.service.factory", value = "com.context.JPAServiceFactory")
})
public class MyODataServlet extends ODataServlet {

}
```

And 2nd service:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/another-odata/*"}, initParams = {
        @WebInitParam(name = "javax.ws.rs.Application", value = "org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.rest.app.ODataApplication"),
        @WebInitParam(name = "org.apache.olingo.odata2.service.factory", value = "com.context.JPAServiceFactory")
})
public class AnotherODataServlet extends ODataServlet {

}
```

Just don't forget to scan them both by using:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        <packages of JPAServiceFactory and other requires beans>
})
@ServletComponentScan(basePackages = <the web servlets package>)
public class ODataConfig {

}
```

Comment: A great answer!